# OSStatus always returns -34018 in Xcode 8 unit tests

Tags: ios, unit-testing, keychain, xcode8, osstatus

I am running few unit tests in my framework project (target is .framework) where I am storing/fetching some data to/from keychain and all my unit tests were working as expected but all of my unit tests are started failing after I upgrade my xcode to xcode8 , unit tests are failing since `OSStatus` always returns -34018

per this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20344255/secitemadd-and-secitemcopymatching-returns-error-code-34018-errsecmissingentit) I have added a run script `codesign --verify --force --sign "$CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY" "$CODESIGNING_FOLDER_PATH"` but no luck its not working how do I fix this, I am blocked because of this please help me out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In iOS10, is it possible to access Keychain from within a static library/framework, for unit testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39538377/in-ios10-is-it-possible-to-access-keychain-from-within-a-static-library-framewo)